# How do I connect to the Bigcommerce API and then process the data using PHP

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am new to how APIs work, I would like to get a specific product from my BigCommerce store using the BigCommerce API. I have read the API documentation, googled quite a lot, but to be honest, I am still a little confused. How do I create a connection to the BigCommerce API and once I create the connection how to I get the product I want from my store.

Answer (score 0):

You must first download this and unpack it on your server (local or web): https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

Once inside the "src" folder, you can create a PHP file that will both authorize your connection and run your script.

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


Bigcommerce::configure(array(

    'store_url' => 'STORE_URL_HERE',
    'username' => 'USERNAME_IN_BACKEND',
    'api_key' => 'API_KEY'
));

Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
```

Create some sort of check that you connected, I think BigCommerce uses a "getTimeStamp" as an example to output if you've correctly connected or not.

That should help you at least connect using PHP, let me know if you need more help.